# bluetooth client scan c#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I'm trying to create a short desktop app using **c#** that allows me to scan bluetooth devices. I used this code (found on this website) :

```
BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
Console.WriteLine("There are:"+devices.Length+" devices");
foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo dev in devices)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found : "+dev.DeviceName);
}
```

Obviously I imported the 32feet.NET dll. This code returns me nothing in the sense that no device is found even if I turn ON some BT devices. 
How can I fix this problem?

[NEW] 
 writing:

```html
            var radios =  BluetoothRadio.AllRadios;
            foreach (BluetoothRadio radio in radios) Console.WriteLine(radio.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Name);
            if (BluetoothRadio.IsSupported) Console.WriteLine("BT radio is supported");
```

I have as result  "MY-PC" and "BT radio is supported"

Comment: In order for bluetooth to work, you have to have a bluetooth radio.  Most desktop computers don't have one.

Comment: Of course I've checked and I have one.

Comment: And is that (in the PC) turned on as well? Ever established a connection?

Comment: Yes I've already done it.